# How to check if pictures in different picBoxes are the same? c# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I'm doing a quiz for Course Work and I have 15 PicBoxes of letter and 6 empty PicBoxes, and I have the picBox letters (they're from the resources) to enter the empty ones in order as they are clicked but I don't know how to check if the letters are in the order that I want them to be for the answer.

I tried this:

```
if ((picAns1.Image == picLetter2.Image) && (picAns2.Image == picLetter10.Image)
```

I'm probably just trying to overthink it but I need help please.

Comment: And what was the result of your test ? What did not work ?

Comment: The `==` operator won't necessarily work depending on how you retrieve the images from your `.resources` / `.resx` files. You'd be better-off separating presentation from program logic: create a view-model representation of the UI and use that for comparison instead of comparing raw view-level objects.

Comment: If you put them in an imagelist you can compare the kaye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier solution I can think of would be to use `PictureBox`'s `Tag` property to define some easily comparable values. When you fill all 6 empty boxes check if it's sorted in order you define.

So if you have letters on those images, just give each `PictureBox` a string tag representing a letter on that image and at the end go through them and find out if they are in the alphabetical order.